# Getting 'referrence error: define is not defined' when I try to load Modernizr

Tags: modernizr

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="en-US"> 

<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/modernizr-custom.js"></script> 
</head>
```

I used the Development Build option on their front page that selects all of the options and I tried minified and not minified but got the same error. I am just downloading the file and placing it in a local folder. I tried it with just selecting the canvas element in thier selection options and it works fine.

This bit of code is what is added in the full feature one and is the line that is giving the error on line 29.

```
;
define("test/network/beacon", function(){});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok they helped me out over there. I was using Ublock and it messed something up.